# Change partial values in input box

Tags: jquery

could someone help me to figure out if it is possible to take part of the value entered into an input field and change the value. What I am trying to do is make sure that addresses are entered correctly. So if someone puts in:

111 Circleview Road it would be changed to 111 Circleview Rd.

This is what I am trying with but having no luck, so I don't know if I am doing this wrong or if this is not possible to do with jQuery

```
$("#address").blur(
function(){
  switch ($(this).val()){
    case 'Road':
    case 'road':
        $(this).replaceWith("Rd.");
    break;
    case 'Street':
    case 'street':
        $(this).replaceWith("St.")
    default:
        $(this).val();
    break;
   }
  }   
);
```

Comment: The `.val()` is going to get the entire value of the `#address` field, which will contain more than just 'Road' or 'street'. You'll want to use substring search and replace functions. Since I don't know the right syntax, I'm making this a comment, but it should get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use regular expression to find the words - it's just string manipulation in JavaScript.

```
$("#myinput").blur(function(){ 
   this.value = this.value
       .replace(/[Rr]oad/g,'Rd.')
       .replace(/[Ss]treet/g,'St.');
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/4Yuym/

You don't need to use `$(this).val()` on an input element since `value` is part of the element's native properties - so you can use `this.value` to get/set.

Comment: This did exactly what I needed. Thank you for taking the time to help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

replaceWith is not the function you are looking for. Try this:

```
var newValue = $(this).val().replace('Road', 'Rd.');
$(this).val(newValue);
```

**EDIT** Also, Brian's response is important too. As your code currently is structured, none of the case statements will execute. Get rid of it and just use this regex.

```
var newValue = $(this).val().replace(/road/gi, 'Rd.')
$(this).val(newValue)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [regualar expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) for that.

```
$(this).val( $(this).val().replace(/Road/, "Rd.") );
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone enters 111 Circleview Road, `$(this).val()` will return that entire string, not just 'Road' or 'Street'.

So, unfortunately I'm not sure that a switch statement will really work for you here.

You may need to use regular expressions instead to find and replace text.